# Matomo - how to group different URLs in tracking / how to track moodle course activity?

Tags: analytics, moodle, matomo

I have the following challenge:

I have a Moodle system and would like to track visitor activity in the courses via Matomo.

The problem is that one course has several activities, but they are found under a different URL structure.

Example: My course has the URL /course/view=1 and also has a few activities that can be found under three completely different URLs (e.g. /mod/forum/view=20, /mod/feedback/view=7 and so on).

Now I would like to have a common tracking for a course room and the activities in it.

Is this possible? Are there any direct solutions for Moodle? Or how could I do this manually in Matomo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set a custom URL in Matomo by using the following code in the page:

```
_paq.push(['setCustomUrl', 'https://yourdomain.com/your-new-page-url']);
```

You could perhaps do this for all the pages within a "Course" in order to track all of the actions taken in one logical "Page", but this may affect some of the reports for that page (For example page overlay might be broken)

An alternate way of tracking all of the actions would be to set the Page Title that Matomo tracks using:

```
_paq.push(['setCustomTitle', 'Your Page Title Here'])
```

This will allow you to group all of the actions under one logical Page Title under the Page Titles report.